# Using ocx File In Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows, dll, windows-services, ocx

I have an ocx file, and I want to use that in Windows Service. I used aximp tool to create dll's from ocx, but those dll's doesn't work, they throws exceptions.

Comment: You'll have to give some more information if you want help.  What exception and what's the code that gives the exception.

Comment: Moving the OCX to a service does not change the requirement of the OCX. For example if its thread apartment is STA, you are responsible to pump windows messages for the OCX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an ocx in a windows service in C# should be like using COM any other time. Just register the ocx as a com server and add a reference to it in the project preferences.

Comment: I registered ocx file to my 64-bit win 7 with

Comment: I registered ocx file to my 64-bit, win 7 operating system, with regsvr32 fk524pxn.ocx command. For debugging I create another project which is winform(x86), then import that ocx file to my winform project, from references. When I debug, it throws a COM exception, which is "Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))". If I turn my winform project to AnyCPU from propeties, then it throws, "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {5AB97943-73D7-4385-BF44-5E4FFCFEBE8C} failed due to the following error: 80040154", COM exception.

Comment: That probelm can arise from your ocx or dll referencing other dlls that aren't registered or can't be found in the windows/system32 folder. Use Dependency Walker, http://www.dependencywalker.com/, to debug that scenario.